# Is it possible to split a nested array to two arrays in Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm getting a array like this

```
var cars = [['BMW'],[],['6000cc']];
```

which contains two different values of a same instance. Here you can see an empty array that's where the data changes. Basically the left side of the empty array contains one set of data and right side of the empty array contains other set of data.

I need to split this array in to two.

Comment: use `splice` to split the array

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please give a better description.

Comment: Ok this is the question.

var cars = [['BMW'],[Benz],[],['6000cc'],[4000cc]];

This array contains details about cars. There is a empty array inside of that cars array and data changes from there. Ex: left side of the array contains names of cars and right side of the array contains capacity of the car. I need to split this cars array and get those data in to two different arrays.

Comment: @Thinker this could be done but time to time the empty array position changes. so can't determine exact index to split.

Comment: so look for the blank.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to split array into two which is separated by empty array. 
First you have to find the index of empty array.

```
var cars = [['BMW'],[],['6000cc']];
var index = -1
for(var i=0;i<cars.length;i++){
if(cars[i].length === 0)
{
index = i;
break;
}
}
```

then you can use slice to split array

```
var arr1 = cars.slice(0, index);
var arr2 = cars.slice(index+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 Array De-structuring and split your arrays.

```
let cars = [['BMW'],[],['6000cc']];
let [cname, other, cpower] = cars;
console.log(cname, cpower);
```

Comment: This only works if number of elements in array are known. Not for generic case

Comment: @amit yes current solution works only when elements are known.